Estimation of distribution algorithms (EDAs) for regularizing logistic regression
can you help me for write python code demonstrates: Estimation of distribution algorithms (EDAs) for regularizing logistic regression. In order to compare it with LASSO, Ridge and Elastic net Regression.
Let's use Cross Validation to find the most suitable Alpha for different models. Then plot the EDA regression coefficients against alpha.
note: can you use Colon Cancer dataset!
l(β)+ λ_1‖β‖_1+λ_2 ‖β-dβ ̂_m2 ‖_2
Let's use Cross Validation to find the most suitable Alpha for different models. Then plot the EDA regression coefficients against alpha.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
